# Running a specific @Issue via gradle

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, junit, spock

I am using Spock to write tests and Gradle to run them. I annotate them using `@Issue`. Tests for the same issue are not necessarily in the same file:

```
FooTest.groovy:

class FooTest extends Specification {
  @Issue("FOOBAR-123")
  def "should foo"() {
    ...
  }
  @Issue("FOOBAR-234")
  def "should bar"() {
    ...
  }
}

BarTest.groovy:

class BarTest extends Specification {
  @Issue("FOOBAR-123")
  def "should quux"() {
    ...
  }
}
```

I would like to run all tests for a single issue (`FOOBAR-123`).

In rspec it would be easy:

```
describe 'foo' do
  it "should foo", foobar-123: true do
    ...
  end

rspec --tag foobar-123
```

But I can't see how to do this with Spock and Gradle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible through the use of extensions. You can do that by creating a file in your project

**IssueIncludeExtension.groovy**

```
package com.tarun.lalwani

import org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractGlobalExtension
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.FeatureInfo
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.SpecInfo
import spock.lang.Issue

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation

class IssueIncludeExtension extends AbstractGlobalExtension{
    @Override
    void visitSpec(SpecInfo spec) {
        def issuesList
        issuesList = System.properties["spock.issues"]

        if (issuesList) {
            def arrIssues = issuesList.split(",").toList()

            System.out.println('I was called')
            for (FeatureInfo feature : spec.getAllFeatures())
            {
                def method, ann;
                method = feature.getFeatureMethod();
                def issueAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(Issue.class);
                if (issueAnnotation) {
                    if (issueAnnotation.value().size() > 0)
                    {
                        if (issueAnnotation.value().toList().intersect(arrIssues))
                        {
                            //we have a matching issue
                            feature.setExcluded(false)
                        } else {
                            feature.setExcluded((true))
                        }


                    }
                } else {
                    // this doesn't belong to any issue
                    feature.setExcluded(true)
                }
            }

        } else {
            super.visitSpec(spec)
        }
    }


}
```

Then in create below file

**META-INF/services/org.spockframework.runtime.extension.IGlobalExtension**

```
com.tarun.lalwani.IssueIncludeExtension
```

After that you can update your gradle script and add a test

```
task issueTest(type: Test) {
    // This task belongs to Verification task group.
    group = 'Verification'

    // Set Spock configuration file when running
    // this test task.
    systemProperty 'spock.issues', 'Issue4'
}
```

Now I have below tests  in groovy

```
package com.mrhaki.spock

import spock.lang.Issue
import spock.lang.Specification

class WordRepositorySpec extends Specification {


    @Remote  // Apply our Remote annotation.
    @Issue(["Issue1", "Issue2"])
    def "test remote access"() {
        given:
        final RemoteAccess access = new RemoteAccess()

        expect:
        access.findWords('S') == ['Spock']
    }

    @Issue("Issue4")
    def "test local access"() {
        given:
        final LocalAccess access = new LocalAccess()

        expect:
        access.findWords('S') == ['Spock']
    }

}
```

Running the test just runs `Issue4` related test

[image: Filter based on issue]

Comment: Thank you, you are a Spock wizard! :)

Comment: Thanks! Honestly through your question only I came to know the existence of Spock :-)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2015/08/spocklight-including-or-excluding.html) article, you may create a configuration for any annotation.

Unfortunately (after some tries) I wasn't able to filter tests against a value of the annotation, the `IncludeExcludeCriteria` class only accepts classes or annotations.

```
runner {
  include spock.lang.Issue
}
```

I think you might get around it with creating annotations per issue and using [Annotations Collectors](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/transform/AnnotationCollector.html).